# Python - Achar impares de uma tupla

Tags: python, python-3.x

Sou novo nessa área e recentemente, para um trabalho da faculdade não consegui transformar essa linha de código em tupla. código da função:

```
def encontra_impares(lista):

    lis = []

    if len(lista) > 0:

        numero = lista.pop(0)

        if numero % 2 != 0:

            lis.append(numero)

        lis = lis + encontra_impares(lista)

    return lis
```

chamada da função:

```
print(encontra_impares([1, 2, 3,5,5,9,7,32,1,6]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode ajustar sua função para algo como:

```
def encontra_impares( tupla ):

    lista = []

    for n in tupla:
        if n % 2 != 0:
            lista.append(n)

    return lista


tpl = (1, 2, 3,5,5,9,7,32,1,6)
lst = encontra_impares( tpl )

print(tpl)
print(lst)
```

Ou Simplesmente:

```
def encontra_impares( tupla ):
    return [ n for n in tupla if n % 2 != 0 ]

tpl = (1, 2, 3,5,5,9,7,32,1,6)
lst = encontra_impares( tpl )

print(tpl)
print(lst)
```

Saída:

```
(1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 9, 7, 32, 1, 6)
[1, 3, 5, 5, 9, 7, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Cara fiquei um pouco confuso com o que exatamente você quer mas de acordo com seu objetivo faria desta forma :

```
 lis=[]
 lista=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9]
      for i in range(len(lista)):
         if lista[i]%2 == 0:
         lis.append(lista[i])
```

Comment: Escrever uma função em python que recebe
como parâmetro uma tupla de números
inteiros. A função deve retornar uma lista com
os valores ímpares da tupla.
essa é a pergunta